# Does Job(Configuration conf) perform shallow copy or deep copy?

Tags: java, apache, hadoop, mapreduce, deep-copy

I found the official documentation for [Job(Configuration conf)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#Job%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) doesn't say this constructor performs either shallow copy or deep copy on the input parameter `conf`, while its static factory constructor [Job.getInstance(Configuration conf)](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.html#getInstance%28org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration%29) does perform a deep copy according to its documentation.  Can I know whether `Job(Configuration conf)` also performs deep copy under all different versions of hadoop release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Job.java?view=markup%20Here) is the link to the current Job.java source.  A quick glance shows that constructor calls `super(conf, null);`, so we need to grab the super class (`JobContext`) for a peek.  The relevant line in that constructor is here:

```
this.conf = new org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobConf(conf);
```

This leads to a call to `JobConf`'s super (`Configuration`).  This leads to [this Configuration constructor](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html).  Relevant text:

> A new configuration with the same settings cloned from another.

You can view the code [here](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.2.1/src/core/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.java?view=markup).

Comment: Thank you for your deep finding !